# PHP display image from link

Tags: php

I am trying to get my image to display when clicked via the link. However when I click on the link it finds the image id as displayed in the url link ok but does not display any image. Can you please help?

```
 <?php

//sets up thisPage          
 $pageSize=10;
  if (isset($_POST["thisPage"])) $thisPage=$_POST["thisPage"];
   else $thisPage=1;



 //selects all distinct expenses that have been uploaded
 $dbQuery="SELECT * FROM images WHERE user_id = '$userID' ";

  $dbResult=mysqli_query($db_connection, $dbQuery) or die(mysqli_error($db_connection));
  echo "<table cellspacing=\"5\" class=\"recordsTableBG\"> <thead 
  class=\"recordsTableHeader\">";
  echo '<tr>     <th>ID</th><th>Amount</th><th>Description</th><th>Filename</th>
   <th>Project ID</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead>';
    echo '<tr class="alternateRowColor">';

   '<tr>';
    while ($dbRow=mysqli_fetch_array($dbResult)){

    echo "<img src = 'uploaded/$image' width = '200' height = '200'>";

  // display row with expense
  echo '<td>'. $dbRow['id'] .'</td>';
 echo '<td>'. $dbRow['user_id']. '</td>';
     echo '<td><a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?imageid='.$dbRow['id'].'>
Click here to view image</a></td>';
    }
 echo "</table>";
 echo "</form>";



   ?>



    <!-- add submitt button
            close form  -->

       </div>
```

Comment: where do you set a value for `$image` variable?

Comment: should i use something like echo '<td>'. $dbRow['image']. '</td>';?

Comment: yes, in img tags like: `echo '<img src="uploaded/'.$dbRow['image'] . ' width="200" height="200" />';` (assuming image is in uploaded folder)

Comment: Your "click here" link is going to have a URL that looks something like `http://localhost/index.php?imageid=1234`. I don't see anything in the script above that will take that `imageid` value from the `$_GET` array and return image data.

Comment: i have tried echo '<img src="uploaded/'.$dbRow['image'] . ' width="200" height="200" />'; but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: If you want to display image content, you should change your header. If you want to just display static image somewhere, you just redirect the browser to the image location

Comment: can you please explain header change? my images are uploaded into an uploaded folder, but trying to retrieve from database so when user clicks a link it will show the image

Answer (score 0):

You have a mixture of two approaches going on here, and that's where the confusion lies.

First, notice your

```
<img src='uploaded/$image' width = '200' height = '200'>
```

The browser is going to see something like

```
<img src='uploaded/picture_of_cat.jpg' width='200' height='200'>
```

and render a 200px by 200px image of a cat. I'm assuming that's your thumbnail. (As an aside, I notice that it's not enclosed in `<td></td>` even though it's in the table row).

In another part of the table, you have

```
<a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?imageid='.$dbRow['id'].'>Click here to view image</a>
```

which is going to render as something like

```
<a href='http://example.com/index.php?imageid=1234'>Click here to view image</a>
```

When the user clicks that link, it's going to make a `GET` request to the server with `imageid` equal to 1234. What is the server going to do with that `imageid`? In the code you've posted, nothing.

You have two choices:

1. if you want to keep the link as it is, you'll have to write some code that will take the `imageid` value, find the appropriate image, and return it to the browser **as image data** - that means setting the appropriate headers and sending the data back as binary data.
2. the simpler way to do it would be to replace the URL in the link with the same one you have in your `<img>` tag - when the user clicks on it, the server will just return the image.